# Где может быть ошибка при отправке текста с edittext на сервер android retrofit?

Tags: android

Я при создании своего приложения использую `retrofit` для общения приложения с сервером. Возникла непонятная для меня ошибка при отправке данных с `EditText`. По документации данные должны быть в формате `string`, я вроде конвертировал текст из полей для ввода в `string`, но по непонятной мне причине у меня посылается не тот текст который я планировал послать.

Вот как я работаю с `EditText`:

```
EditText subject, body;

subject = findViewById(R.id.subject);
body = findViewById(R.id.body);

String a = subject.toString();
String b = body.toString();
```

Дальше я вставляю полученный `String` в тело запроса:

```
mAPIService.send_message("Bearer " + access_token, new SendMessage(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<SendMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SendMessage> call, Response<SendMessage> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SendMessage> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

если смотреть по логам то все нормально, запрос шлется, но почему-то в теле не то что нужно. Вероятнее всего я неправильно конвертирую символы из полей для ввода в строковые переменные, но я по-другому не знаю как конвертировать в строки.

Если кто-то понял где у меня ошибка, то я буду очень рад если вы мне поможете решить данную проблему.

Comment: `subject.getText().toString()` для `body` аналогично.

Comment: помогло, спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `toString` который вы вызвали у `EditText` вызывается у прародителя-класса `Object`, который по умолчанию возвращает хэш-код обьекта в куче. У `EditText` есть метод `getText()`, возвращающий (вроде) `CharSequence`, в котором переопределен метод `toString()`, возвращающий строку, находящуюся в `EditText`.