# записывает переменную не правильно

Tags: java, android, firebase

У меня есть код который отправляет в firebase firestore имя пользователя (то которое он ввел в поле), но почему-то записывается не просто текст а вот это:

```
  androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{98e123e VFED..CL. ........ 0,747-1222,952 
  #7f0800f8 app:id/inputName}`
```

Понятия не имею почему, вот код который отправлеяет это в firebase:

```
private void signUp() {
    // loading(true);

    FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    HashMap<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, binding.inputName.toString());
    database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                // loading(false);
                String userName = binding.inputName.getText().toString();

                preferenceManager.putBoolean(Constants.KEY_IS_SIGNED_IN, true);
                preferenceManager.putString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID, documentReference.getId());
                preferenceManager.putString(Constants.KEY_NAME, userName);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                showToast(exception.getMessage());
            });
}
```

В файле costants лежит вот это:

```
public static final String KEY_COLLECTION_USERS = "users";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PREFERENCE_NAME = "fllafPreference";
public static final String KEY_IS_SIGNED_IN = "isSignedIn";
public static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userId";
public static final String KEY_USER = "user";
```

Я новичок в андроид студио поэтому много-чего не знаю.

Comment: `user.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, binding.inputName.toString());` - пропустили `getText()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Где может быть ошибка при отправке текста с edittext на сервер android retrofit?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874395/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-edittext-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-android-retrofit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции **signUp()** вы пропустили **getText()**.
Т.е вызывали **toString()**, на **AppCompatEditText**.
Оттуда вы и получали такое имя юзера

> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{98e123e VFED..CL.
> ........ 0,747-1222,952    #7f0800f8 app:id/inputName}`

Вот исправленная функция:

```
private void signUp() {
// loading(true);

FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
HashMap<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, binding.inputName.getText()toString());
database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
            // loading(false);
            String userName = binding.inputName.getText().toString();

            preferenceManager.putBoolean(Constants.KEY_IS_SIGNED_IN, true);
            preferenceManager.putString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID, documentReference.getId());
            preferenceManager.putString(Constants.KEY_NAME, userName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
            showToast(exception.getMessage());
        });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое. я 10 раз все перепроверял и не заметил этого(